# element changes applied in an "each" loop don't show until after the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery each loop that applies a class to a set of elements - however, the change isn't reflected until the loop is done. (Before you jump on me for my methodology this is for debugging purposes on a back-end interface that isn't public-facing.)

```
var x = 0;
function doTheThing() {
    var ids=[10, 20, 30]; 
    $.each(ids,function(a,b){
        $("#field_" + b).click(); // should do something that shows in the interface
        $("#field_" + b).addClass("workedon"); // should also do something
        sleep(2000); // wait a bit to see that it happens - which it doesn't, not yet
    });
    console.log('done')
    // and all the changes made above show up all at once
}    
j(".theFields").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    // all the stuff happens here
    // except what's supposed to show in the interface
    console.log('doing stuff');
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid red"); // << doesn't happen
    x += 1; // << no problem
    console.log(x);
});

function sleep(ms) {
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < ms);
}

doTheThing();
```

output:

```
doing stuff
1
doing stuff
2
doing stuff
3
done
```

So, nothing visual happens while we're in the loop. After the loop all the changes show up at once. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly? (Please don't get hung up on the sleep function. I know there's a more modern way, but that's not my question.)

Comment: That's the way browsers work. They don't render anything until all the JavaScript finishes.

Comment: What do jQuery animations do differently, then?

Comment: They use timers and CSS transitions.